# Uncertainty Principle for locally compact groups.

Tags: fourier-analysis, representation-theory, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

The uncertainty principle is a general fact about the Fourier transform on locally compact Abelian groups. However, the precise uncertainty principle depends on the type of group. For example, it is well-known that on the additive group of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, a function $f$ and its Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ can not both be compactly supported. But this depends on certain specific properties of $\mathbb{R}$. I was wondering if it is possible for a function on a non-Euclidean group and its Fourier transform to both have compact support.

I have the mind to consider the Fourier transform on the p-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ or on the p-adic rationals $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$, but unfortunately, I am not yet familiar with the Fourier analysis on these groups to produce an example or some kind of argument very quickly.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: there are statements on non-zero entries of DFT,  e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0308286, i think the result in this link has been generalized, but i can not recall where i saw it